# Overflow - hidden and floated left elements

Tags: css

I have a series of div's as columns in a parent div which is set to overflow hidden, but the columns are wrapping when the reach the right hand side of the container instead of overflowing.

This is a basic version of the code.

```
.column{
width:200px;
float:left;
}
<div style="overflow:hidden">
<div class="column"></div>
<div class="column"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to avoid wrapping in CSS float](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3572492/how-to-avoid-wrapping-in-css-float)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use inline-bock instead of float:left;

http://jsfiddle.net/RgJk9/1/

```
.container { width: 300px; overflow: scroll; white-space: nowrap; }

.column{
  background-color: red;
  width:200px;
  height: 200px;
  display: inline-block;
}​
```

With the HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="column"></div>
  <div class="column"></div>
</div>​
```

Comment: That seemed to work although I needed white-space: nowrap; on the conatiner as well.

Comment: You really only need it on the container, the columns shouldn't need it unless there's a wrapping issue inside of them.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
div.column {
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    width: 200px;
}
```

This will hide any overflow, and force text to not wrap, keeping it all on one line.

For newer browsers, CSS supports the `ellipsis` property for `text-overflow` to add a nice touch.